# Calling C++ function from Fortran in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to call a C++ function from Fortran. To do that, I make a FORTRAN project in Visual Studio 2010. After that I add a Cpp project to that FORTRAN project. The following errors occur when I want to build the program:

```
Error 1: unresolved external symbol print_C referenced in function MAIN_main.obj    
Error 2:    1 unresolved externals
```

Following are the Fortran program and C++ function.

Fortran program:

```fortran
program main

  use iso_c_binding, only : C_CHAR, C_NULL_CHAR
  implicit none

  interface
    subroutine print_c ( string ) bind ( C, name = "print_C" )
      use iso_c_binding, only : C_CHAR
      character ( kind = C_CHAR ) :: string ( * )
    end subroutine print_c
  end interface

  call print_C ( C_CHAR_"Hello World!" // C_NULL_CHAR )
end
```

C++ function:

```c++
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

void print_C ( char *text )

{
  printf ( "%s\n", text );

  return;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You tagged it as "C++", but speak of a "C function". So in which language do you compile it, C or C++? Note that for code that works the same both in C and in C++ there still are differences between both when linking is concerned.

Comment: Thank you Dear.
That is C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to mix fortran and C++ in visual studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379086/how-to-mix-fortran-and-c-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that since you compile with a C++ compiler, `print_C` is not a C function, but a C++ function. Since the Fortran code tries to call a C function, it cannot find the C++ function.

The solution to your problem therefore is

- either compile with a C compiler, so you get actual C code,
- or tell the C++ compiler that you actually want to declare a C function.

The latter is done with `extern "C"`, like this:

```
extern "C" void print_C(char *text)
{
  printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

If you want to be able to compile your code both as C and as C++, you can use

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void print_C(char *text)
{
  printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

The symbol `__cplusplus` is defined for C++, but not for C, so your code will work in both (of course only as long as the rest of your code also remains in that subset).

Comment: I did Both of them but, the above mentioned problems are not solved!

Comment: @Mortezanamvar Did you get it to work? I just tried this exact code and it ran just fine. Did you link the object file created by your C++ compiler?

Comment: No, that did not work. I think by adding the interface to Fortran, C++ function will be link to Fortran. Is it true or not?